# Не отображается текс

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, move, show

Есть два файла

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel

class Chel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setText('1')
```

и

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton
from chel import Chel

class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Координаты')
        self.setFixedSize(700, 700)

        self.coords = QPushButton(self)
        self.coords.setText("Координаты: None, None")
        self.coords.clicked.connect(self.change)
        self.coords.move(200, 200)

    def change(self):
        self.g = Chel(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Текст '1' при нажатие не отображается в окне. Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Укажите позицию виджета в его родительском виджете:

```
self.g.move(250, 150)
```

Покажите виджет:

```
self.g.show()
```

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton, QLabel

#from chel import Chel
class Chel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setText('1')


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
#        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Координаты')
#        self.setFixedSize(500, 500)

        self.coords = QPushButton(self)
        self.coords.setText("Координаты: None, None")
        self.coords.clicked.connect(self.change)
        self.coords.move(200, 200)

    def change(self):
        self.g = Chel(self)
        self.g.move(250, 150)                                     # +++
        self.g.show()                                             # +++
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.resize(500, 500)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

У виджета нужно ещё вызвать метод show.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel

class Chel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setText('1')
        self.show() #+++
```

Результат: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: нет, этого недостаточно.

Comment: Я запустил пример и он работает, вы можете пояснить что ещё нужно?